# How do i check for a label in neo4j 2.1.2 when using a legacy index?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I just upgraded to Neo4j 2.1.2 from 2.0.1 and some of my cypher-queries stopped working.
I am using a self-defined Lucene index to find the startnodes, navigate via a typed relationship (Partner_PartnerMeta) to a typed Node(PartnerTyp). After that i just return a subset of these nodes.

My query previously used to check for the type of startnode (PartnerMeta). Since 2.1.2 the query

```
START partnermeta = node:PartnerTyp_Meta("Namen:wilhelm*") 
MATCH (partner:PartnerTyp)-[:Partner_PartnerMeta]->(partnermeta:PartnerMeta)
RETURN DISTINCT partner SKIP 0 LIMIT 10
```

results in

```
Cannot add labels or properties on a node which is already bound (line 2, column 52)
"MATCH (partner:PartnerTyp)-[:Partner_PartnerMeta]->(partnermeta:PartnerMeta)"
                                                    ^
```

This error can be suppressed by omitting the ":PartnerMeta" part of the query. As the type of the node returned from the index hasn't been checked yet, i would like to verify that it is of the type "PartnerMeta" (maybe i am too paranoid that way).

My question is:
Is there a possibility to check for the type of node after the usage of START in combination with a legacy index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regression in Cypher 2.1.2 which will be fixed. It was an attempt to avoid invalid combinations of label checks.

For now, can you try:

```
START partnermeta = node:PartnerTyp_Meta("Namen:wilhelm*") 
MATCH (partner:PartnerTyp)-[:Partner_PartnerMeta]->(partnermeta)
WHERE partnermeta:PartnerMeta
RETURN DISTINCT partner SKIP 0 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked just fine. It didnt occur to me to formulate the requirement in a where-clause.